# Why is my text shown out of div?

Tags: html, css

I am unable to figure out whats wrong , my expectation from below code is that the text should be shown inside the div which is marked by blue background and border, but it is shown below the div, why is it happening?

```css
.item-header {
  background-color: rgb(0, 246, 246);
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-style: double;
  height: 20px;
}

.alignleft {
  background: transparent;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

.alignright {
  background: transparent;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-header">

  <p class="alignleft">Author: {{post.author}}</p>
  <p class="alignright" (click)="ratingEditorClicked()">bias :{{post.bias_rating}}/5
    <ion-icon name="create" item-right></ion-icon>
  </p>

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Clear your floats.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove the `height` from the `.item-header{`
Then the other problem was the float. If you float elements inside an element it kinda looses the height. One solution to this is to clear floats with a pseudo element (`:after`), have a look at:

```
.item-header:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```css
.item-header{
  background-color: rgb(0,246,246);
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-style: double;
  /*height: 20px;*/
}

.item-header:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.alignleft {
  background: transparent;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}
.alignright {
  background: transparent;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
 <div class="item-header"  >

  <p class="alignleft">Author: {{post.author}}</p>
  <p class="alignright" (click)="ratingEditorClicked()">bias :{{post.bias_rating}}/5
     <ion-icon name="create" item-right ></ion-icon>
  </p>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In reality it actually is. It is because you are hardcoding the `height` in `.item-header` that it is looking like that.

If you use `display:inline-block`, the text will go into the div.

[JSFiddle with example fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/osxmomhk/)

Answer (score 0):

Because the inner divs are `float`. And you have set `20px of height` in .item-header

You need to use the clearfix hack on these type of designs.

```css
.item-header {
  background-color: rgb(0, 246, 246);
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-style: double;

}

.alignleft {
  background: transparent;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
}

.alignright {
  background: transparent;
  float: right;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-header">

  <p class="alignleft">Author: {{post.author}}</p>
  <p class="alignright" (click)="ratingEditorClicked()">bias :{{post.bias_rating}}/5
    <ion-icon name="create" item-right></ion-icon>
  </p>
  <div class='clearfix'/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By the names of your CSS classes I asume you want, besides the text in the blue box, the `p.alignleft` aligned to left in the same row as a *column* regarding  the `p.alignright` If so, you could also do this:

[demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/8od7ajx6/2/)